# Why is textarea draggable in Firefox 5?

Tags: html, firefox

See [this link](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_text_box_code.cfm) - why are the multiline textboxes draggable?
Is this Firefox bug? It just spoils the design like anything.
Even the same in happening is Stackoverflow's textbox. I am using Firefox 5.0

Thanks in advance:)

**Edit:**

See these photos of SO itself:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature that's been included since Firefox 4. However, you can switch it off by including `resize: none` in the css of the given Textarea(s).

Answer (score 2):

That's something happening since some time now even on Chrome and maybe other browsers too. I think it's to allow a better experience for the users who need to type text in the textarea, so I definitely think it's not a bug.

But it indeed can mess up your website layout. You have to use some CSS to fix it, like

```
#yourtextarea {
  width: /* fixed width here */
  height: /* fixed height here */
}
```

In case the above doesn't work, you may also think about use `min-width`, `max-width`, and the height equivalents.

I won't mess up with this anyway, since it's a browser feature and so it's something useful for the users.

Comment: But it spoils the design. What purpose does it serve? See the SO design in 2nd picture.

Comment: I think it's useful when you want more space to type text, for example when you want to type code, since textareas will usually word-wrap your long lines and that may be something unwanted. Or simply when you have to type something long, you may want to have your text completely displayed, for a quick review and overall feeling if what you are writing make sense or not...

Answer (score 0):

> Why are the multiline textboxes draggable?

They aren't. Dragging just selects the text inside them. They *can* be resized though, which is great as it lets users make textboxes bigger so they can see more of their text if they have typed a lot.

> Is this Firefox bug?

No, it is a feature. I *think* Chrome got it first.

Comment: But it spoils the design. What purpose does it serve? See the SO design in 2nd picture.

Comment: It makes many sites more comfortable for users since web designers expect users to type in long texts in a 5x8 character textarea ... :-(